# Utilizing OCLHashcat to crack WPA/WPA2 passwords obtained via airodump-ng

Tags: wifi, wpa2, aircrack-ng, hashcat

Wondering if its possible (edit - Found ways to do so, the question now is does it make more sense) to do so? Did a little bit of searching but it would seem that most people utilize Aircrack-NG. Hashcat would allow you to utilize your GPU, and access to rule-based dictionary attacks - Is there some feature in Aircrack-NG that im missing that would make it superior to cracking these? Or just convenience? Not worth the setup time if you don't have a strong GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to cracking WPA/WPA2 with Hashcat or Aircrack-ng, I recommend using Hashcat.  It provides a number of builtin features that can prove to be very effective.

Hashcat has builtin rule sets and easy to use GPU support.  For example, the rule sets provide a simple way to create new passwords out of you existing password dictionary.  This is builtin to Hashcat and doesn't require using another tool (such as John The Ripper) to apply the rule sets to your password dictionary.

Hashcat has most of the functionality you'll want for cracking WPA/WPA2 baked right in. Also, if you are serious about cracking passwords, you'll likely always want to use GPUs for this type of task.